# Dynamically populate radio buttons based select-element choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, radio-button

My form has a select element and a group of radio-buttons. The values (and labels) of the radio buttons depend on which option was selected in the select-element. My plan is to house the radio buttons in a partial, and when the selected option changes, make an AJAX call to retrieve an updated version of it, then reinsert it into the form.

Is that a sensible solution? I know this could be handled better by Angular, but converting this page to an Angular app is probably beyond the scope of this small project.

*Edit*: I guess what I'm really asking is whether making an AJAX call for the radio buttons is a better solution than having all the radio buttons already on the page and using js/jquery to manipulate them (show/hide, check/uncheck).

Comment: I do know a thing or two about forms and Ajax, but what do you mean with "My plan is to house the radio buttons in a partial"? What is a partial?

Comment: In Rails, a partial is a chunk of view-code (dynamically generated html) that can be inserted into a page

Comment: OK, so then your question is one about RoR rather than about Ajax? If so, I won't be able to help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm interested in general approach, not framework specific.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here a generic approach, using native/vanilla Javascript. This is the code for a page in which the radio buttons must be loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo radio loading w/ Ajax</title>
<style>
#radioContainer {
    width: 275px;
    height: 125px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="theForm">

        <select name="preSelector" onchange="loadRadios()">
            <option value=""> Select the car brand </option>
            <option value="audi.html"> Audi </option>
            <option value=""> BMW </option>
            <option value=""> Mercedes </option>
        </select>

        <div id="radioContainer">

        </div>

    </form>

    <script>
    function loadRadios() {
        var selectValue = filePath = theForm.elements['preSelector'].value;
        var radioContainer = document.getElementById('radioContainer');
        var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (selectValue != '') {
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                    radioContainer.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
            }
            ajaxRequest.open('GET',filePath,true);
            ajaxRequest.send();
        }
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the -- whole -- code of the file with the Audi radio buttons, audi.html:

```
<h3>Audi</h3>

<label>4-wheel drive: </label> yes <input type="radio" name="audi_4wheel" value="yes"> no <input type="radio" name="audi_4wheel" value="no">
    <br>
<label>Airconditioning: </label> yes <input type="radio" name="audi_airco" value="yes"> no <input type="radio" name="audi_airco" value="no">
    <br>
<label>Metallic paint: </label> yes <input type="radio" name="audi_metallic" value="yes"> no <input type="radio" name="audi_metallic" value="no">
```

.
That file should be put in the same directory as the 'mother page', or the path must be adapted.

I am assuming that you don't need to code for IE6; the code works in IE7+ and all other browsers. I should think that for you, the code is pretty much self-explanatory, for the rest. If not, just post a comment question, and I'll be happy to answer it.